# IdentityServer3 login loop for clients using different flows

Tags: identityserver3

Our IdentityServer3 services is acting oddly, when we try to login from a client using hybrid flow and then login from a different client using implicit flow. The second user is stuck in a loop where the STS fails to recognize the authorization and sends the user back to the login page repeatedly. We can recreate this behavior and see it in our log files. Also, which client is logged on first that can login successfully, while the second one gets stuck in the loop. We have implemented a custom login process using the hooks for IdentityServer3. Below is the code for the login process:

```
public class EmsUserService : UserServiceBase
{
    private IEmsEntities _context
    {
        get
        {
            var container = DependencyResolver.Current;
            var service = container.GetService<IEmsEntities>();
            service.ChangeReadUncommittedSetting(true);
            return service;


        }
    }

    public override Task PreAuthenticateAsync(PreAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var personId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
            var user = _context.Person.Include(p => p.PersonLogin).First(x => x.PersonId.ToString() == personId);

            context.AuthenticateResult = new AuthenticateResult(personId, user.PersonLogin.LoginName);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }


    public override Task AuthenticateLocalAsync(LocalAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        var password = context.Password;
        var encryptPassword = Password.Encrypt(password);

        var allUserLoginRecords = Utilities.GetUserLoginRecords(_context, encryptPassword, context.UserName);

        //We want to make sure that we recognize if a user already exists but is locked out. "Locked out" is determined by a username/password
        //that matches but is not currently active
        if (allUserLoginRecords.Any())
        {
            if (allUserLoginRecords.Any(u => u.PersonLogin.IsActive))
            {
                var active = allUserLoginRecords.First(u => u.PersonLogin.IsActive);
                var isOld = Utilities.IsOld(active.PersonLogin);
                var isComplex = Utilities.IsComplex(context.Password);
                var resetRequired = active.PersonLogin.IsResetRequired;


                if (isOld || !isComplex || resetRequired)
                {
                    context.AuthenticateResult = new AuthenticateResult(String.Format("~/ChangePassword/{0}", isOld),
                        active.PersonId.ToString(),
                        active.PersonLogin.LoginName);
                }
                else
                {
                    context.AuthenticateResult = new AuthenticateResult(active.PersonId.ToString(),
                        active.PersonLogin.LoginName);
                }
            }


            else
            {
                context.AuthenticateResult =
                    new AuthenticateResult(
                        "This account has been locked. Please contact OSPI Customer Support to re-activate it.");
            }
        }

        else
        {
            context.AuthenticateResult =
                new AuthenticateResult(
                    "The username and password combination does not match. Your username must be an email address and the password is case-sensitive.");
        }
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }




    public override Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        var subjectId = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();



        // issue the claims for the users
        var user = _context.Person.Include(p => p.PersonLogin).First(x => x.PersonId.ToString() == subjectId && x.PersonLogin.IsActive);
        if (user != null)
        {
            var emailClaim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.PersonLogin.LoginName);
            claims.Add(emailClaim);
            var nameClaim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.PersonId.ToString());
            claims.Add(nameClaim);
            context.IssuedClaims = claims;
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }



    public override Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        var subjectId = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();

        // Look up the user to make sure that they're active
        var user = _context.Person.Include(p => p.PersonLogin).First(x => x.PersonId.ToString() == subjectId && x.PersonLogin.IsActive);
        if (user == null)
        {
            context.IsActive = false;
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        context.IsActive = true;
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Here are the IdentityServer logs for the second client trying to log in:

```
> w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2016-09-29 10:07:08.008 -07:00 [Information] User is not authenticated. Redirecting to login.
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2016-09-29 10:07:08.009 -07:00 [Information] End authorize request
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2016-09-29 10:07:08.010 -07:00 [Information] Redirecting to login page
2016-09-29 10:07:08.011 -07:00 [Debug] Protecting message: "{\"ReturnUrl\":\"https://localhost/OspiSts/identity/connect/authorize?client_id=.....&redirect_uri=......&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code%20id_token%20token&scope=openid%20profile%20authApi&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%.....\",\"ClientId\":\"....",\"AcrValues\":[],\"Created\":636107656279778454}"
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2016-09-29 10:07:08.018 -07:00 [Information] Login page requested
2016-09-29 10:07:08.019 -07:00 [Debug] signin message passed to login: "{
  \"ReturnUrl\": \"......",
  \"ClientId\": \"...",
  \"IdP\": null,
  \"Tenant\": null,
  \"LoginHint\": null,
  \"DisplayMode\": null,
  \"UiLocales\": null,
  \"AcrValues\": [],
  \"Created\": 636107656279778454
}"
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2016-09-29 10:07:12.847 -07:00 [Information] rendering login page
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2016-09-29 10:07:21.148 -07:00 [Information] Login page submitted
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2016-09-29 10:07:27.417 -07:00 [Information] Login credentials successfully validated by user service
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2016-09-29 10:07:27.419 -07:00 [Information] {
  "Category": "Authentication",
  "Name": "Local Login Success",
  "EventType": "Success",
  "Id": 1010,
  "Details": {
    "LoginUserName": "...",
    "SignInId": "...",
    "SignInMessage": {
      "ReturnUrl": "....",
      "ClientId": "...",
      "AcrValues": [],
      "Created": 636107656279778454
    },
    "PartialLogin": false,
    "SubjectId": "141480",
    "Name": "..."
  },
  "Context": {
    "ActivityId": "77206837-cc1c-475b-a3e0-9b362b9dad29",
    "TimeStamp": "2016-09-29T17:07:27.4199277+00:00",
    "ProcessId": 1712,
    "MachineName": "WKS-C070421",
    "RemoteIpAddress": "::1"
  }
}
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2016-09-29 10:07:27.421 -07:00 [Information] Calling PostAuthenticateAsync on the user service
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2016-09-29 10:07:27.425 -07:00 [Information] issuing primary signin cookie
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2016-09-29 10:07:27.428 -07:00 [Information] redirecting to: ....
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2016-09-29 10:07:27.442 -07:00 [Information] Start authorize request
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2016-09-29 10:07:27.443 -07:00 [Information] Start authorize request protocol validation
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2016-09-29 10:07:27.479 -07:00 [Information] "Authorize request validation success"
 "{
  \"ClientId\": \"...",
  \"ClientName\": \"Data Quality\",
  \"RedirectUri\": \"...",
  \"AllowedRedirectUris\": [
    \"...",
    \"....",
    \"....",
    \"...."
  ],
  \"SubjectId\": \"unknown\",
  \"ResponseType\": \"code id_token token\",
  \"ResponseMode\": \"form_post\",
  \"Flow\": \"Hybrid\",
  \"RequestedScopes\": \"openid profile authApi\",
  \"State\": \"OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties=....",
  \"Nonce\": \"..",
  \"Raw\": {
    \"client_id\": \"...",
    \"redirect_uri\": \"...",
    \"response_mode\": \"form_post\",
    \"response_type\": \"code id_token token\",
    \"scope\": \"openid profile authApi\",
    \"state\": \"OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties=...",
    \"nonce\": \"..."
  }
}"
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2016-09-29 10:07:27.480 -07:00 [Information] User is not authenticated. Redirecting to login.
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2016-09-29 10:07:27.481 -07:00 [Information] End authorize request
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2016-09-29 10:07:27.483 -07:00 [Information] Redirecting to login page
2016-09-29 10:07:27.484 -07:00 [Debug] Protecting message: "{\"ReturnUrl\":\"..",\"ClientId\":\"...",\"AcrValues\":[],\"Created\":636107656474419255}"
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2016-09-29 10:07:27.493 -07:00 [Information] Login page requested
2016-09-29 10:07:27.495 -07:00 [Debug] signin message passed to login: "{
  \"ReturnUrl\": \"...",
  \"ClientId\": \"...",
  \"IdP\": null,
  \"Tenant\": null,
  \"LoginHint\": null,
  \"DisplayMode\": null,
  \"UiLocales\": null,
  \"AcrValues\": [],
  \"Created\": 636107656474419255
}"
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2016-09-29 10:07:28.657 -07:00 [Information] rendering login page
```

You can see that I am redirected to the login, I login in successfully, but the STS fails to recognize the authentication. This occurs for the second client when logging in regardless of which one that is.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in Microsoft's Owin implementation for System.Web. The one that is being used when running Owin applications on IIS. Which is what probably 99% of us do, if we're using the new Owin-based authentication handling with ASP.NET MVC5.

The bug makes cookies set by Owin mysteriously disappear on some occasions.

This middleware is a fix for that bug. Simple add it before any cookie handling middleware and it will preserve the authentication cookies. Here is the link

https://github.com/KentorIT/owin-cookie-saver